# export to pdf not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

can any one help me export the pdftable in pdf . my file is not getting exported to pdf and it also not showing any error i have written a code below code for export to pdf but it is not working properly i have use itextsharp dll for writing the code

```
her is my code

 Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                Paragraph p, p1, p2;
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                string imagepath = GetImageUrl("images");

                iTextSharp.text.Image gif = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/Logo.png");
                p2 = new Paragraph();
                p2.Add(gif);
                p2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                pdfDoc.Add(p2);

                p1 = new Paragraph(new Phrase(new Chunk(" INVOICE ", FontFactory.GetFont("verdana", 15, BaseColor.GRAY))));
                p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfDoc.Add(p1);

                p = new Paragraph(new Chunk("\n"));
                pdfDoc.Add(p);
                pdfDoc.Add(table1);

                pdfDoc.Add(table);
                string str = "This is a computer generated invoice. Please contact MSWindowsCare billing for more information at billing@mswindowscare.com";
                p = new Paragraph(str, FontFactory.GetFont("verdana", 7, BaseColor.GRAY));
                p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                pdfDoc.Add(p);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + "filename=SalesInvoice.pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do some debugging. First thing I would do is write out the pdfDoc to a file and check whether this actually is correct pdf or empty or something.

Basically replace:

```
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
```

with something putting it to the dile system then try to open it.

And then take it from there. THis helps you nail down the issue.

Never used PdfWriter but I think the line up may not write the bytes of the pdf as you think it does. The result would be an obvious error on the client, not on the server.